# trying to find the maximum and minimum of numbers inputted into the command line

Tags: c

Basically what I'm trying to do is read numbers of the command line and then print the maximum and the minimum number only. It worked for the maximum so my thougth process is basically to just copy that and invert it, but that doesnt work. Any suggestions welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>   

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    double max = INT_MIN;
    double min = INT_MAX;

 //maximum   
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) 
        {                
        double n = 0;                                  
        if (sscanf (argv[i], "%lf", &n) == 1) 
            {      
                if (n > max)                            
                max = n;                            
            }
        }

 //minimum
    for (int j = 1; j > argc; --j) 
    {               
        double m = 0;                                  
        if (sscanf (argv[j], "%lf", &m) == 1) 
            {      
                if (m < min)                        
                min = m;                            
            }
    }

    printf ("max: %lf\nmin: %lf", max, min);
}
```

Would also be appreciated for hints on how to do a total for numbers read on the command line.
For example the output would be something like:
11 numbers read;   max: 9.52;   min: -13.47.

Comment: `double max = INT_MIN; double min = INT_MAX;` should be `double max = -DBL_MAX; double min = DBL_MAX;` You can check them both in the same loop, the sequence does not matter.

Comment: Look at your second loop again: `for (int j = 1; j > argc; --j)` When you switched from max to min you went a bit too far. The loop will not iterate at all

Comment: @Gerhardh I know that it does go too far but I'm not really sure what to change to limit it.

Comment: Just do it in the first loop (test `n` again).

Comment: As mentioned already, your second loop doesn't run even once. The stop condition is `j > argc`. It means that if J is bigger than argc, continue with the execution of the loop. You can copy the stop condition and increment j (instead of decremnt it), or just use the first loop to find the max and the min at the same iteration.

Comment: With "too far" I meant that changing the loop was not necessary. You must do exactly the same thing than for maximum to get the numbers. Just the comparison with `min` needs to be different.

Comment: As for "hints on how to do a total" put `double sum = 0;` and total it with `sum += n;` in the same loop. You only need *one loop*.

Comment: @WeatherVane Aside: Rather than `DBL_MAX`, could use `HUGE_VAL` to cope better with infinities.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing up two principles here, let's shed some light, using this example for input values:

```
4 6 8 2
```

Result:

```
min : 2
max : 8
```

How to get them? (Pseudo-code)

```
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;

for (int index = 0; index < argc; index++)
{
  if (argv[index] > max) 
    { max = argv[index]; }
  if (argv[index] < min) 
    { min = argv[index]; }
  write_output(index, max, min);
}
```

When running this, these will be the values of `max` and `min`:

```
index    max    min
    0      4      4
    1      6      4
    2      8      4
    3      8      2  => final values
```

What's the story with inversing about? Well, imagine that, instead of just looking for maximum and minimum, you are sorting the values, then you can simply pick the maximum and minimum at both ends of the sorted result (or take the same end when sorting in the inverse order). As, however, in this particular case, you are not sorting, there is no need to inverse anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Dominique answer, and your method of handling inputs arguments, I would do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>   

int main (int argc, char **argv)  {
    double max = INT_MIN;
    double min = INT_MAX;
    int correctly_read_numbers = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {               
        double n = 0;
        int ret = sscanf (argv[i], "%lf", &n);
        if (ret == 1) {      
            if (n > max)                            
                max = n; 
            if (n < min)
                min = n;
            correctly_read_numbers++;
        }
    }
    printf ("%d numbers read; max: %lf\nmin: %lf", correctly_read_numbers, max, min);
}
```

I have not compiled neither tried this code, but it seams to work the way you want.

It's a good practice to avoid as much as possible unnecessary loops. In that case it's not much of a problem, but when coming to the case of nested loops it could become a real time consuming process.